# flatten array of arrays into a vector of arrays

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I'm generating matrix representations of images with **height*width** size, and I need to transform them in a vector of pixels. To generate the images, I'm using the following instruction

```
np.array([[np.random.randint(0, 255, 3) for dummy_row in range(height)] for dummy_col in range(width)])
```

e.g., (2x2) image

```
array([[[132, 235,  40],
        [234,   1, 160]],
       [[ 69, 108, 218],
        [198, 179, 165]]])
```

I tried to use flatten(), but is not creating a one-dimension array of pixels, but is pilling all the values together

```
array([132, 235,  40, 234,   1, 160,  69, 108, 218, 198, 179, 165])
```

when I'm requiring

```
array([132, 235,  40], [234,   1, 160],  [69, 108, 218], [198, 179, 165]])
```

is there a built-in function to get this output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use:

```
arr.reshape(-1, n_channels)
```

or similar (where `arr` is the NumPy array containing the image data).